# Mocking a val of a trait with scala-mock

Tags: scala, unit-testing, mocking, scalamock

I'd like to mock a val of a trait. for example, in this code, to mock the val `baz`:

```
trait Foo {
  def bar(): Int
  val baz: Int
}

val fooMock = mock[Foo]
(fooMock.bar _).expects().returning(5)
(fooMock.baz _).expects().returning(6) //doesn't compile

doSomeThing(fooMock)
```

To solve this in my test, I've extended Foo, and implemented `baz` in the following manner:

```
trait FooTest extends Foo {
  override val baz: Int = 5
}

val fooMock = mock[FooTest]
(fooMock.bar _).expects().returning(6)

doSomeThing(fooMock)
```

But this is ugly, and I was hoping that there is a more standard way of doing this with scala mock.

I've seen the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626491/mocking-scala-traits-containing-abstract-val-members), but it requires changing the `val` to `def` in the trait, and I'd like to keep `baz` a val

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't supported by ScalaMock's macro-based mocks as things currently stand. It is one of the things that we hope to address when [scala.meta](http://scalameta.org) becomes available.

If you want to track this, you might want to follow:

https://github.com/paulbutcher/ScalaMock/issues/40

There is another option that might be of interest - ScalaMocks's proxy-based mocks do support mocking vals. For an example, see the ScalaMock test suite:

https://github.com/paulbutcher/ScalaMock/blob/master/core_tests/src/test/scala/com/paulbutcher/test/proxy/ProxyMockTest.scala#L163

Comment: I wasn't aware of the proxy mocks. The test file gives some good examples, but is there any documentations about it?

Comment: Apologies, but the documentation for proxy mocks is (as you've seen) thin on the ground. The good thing is that they're much simpler than macro-based mocks, so pretty much the examples in the test file are "it" :-)

Comment: Is it still not supported in the newer versions?